# I can't draw on a mouselistener component

Tags: java, swing, components, graphics2d, mouselistener

I can't post any code right now, since the computer I'm programming on has no internet connection, and I absolutely refuse to write it out on this phone.

Basically, I have a `JPanel` (which implements mouseListener), which contains a `Component` in its contentPane. The `JPanel` is listening for mouse events on the `Component`.

When I draw to the panel, it works fine except that the area under the `Component` (which is visible but not painting anything) just shows the Panel's background (a standard colour fill) and not the image I drew on top of it.

I get the feeling that I'm missing something fundamental to do with mouseListeners...

OK, here's the whole class, now that my computer's working as intended again:

(Also, it seems I was using Labels, not Components. Sorry about that.)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.*;

public class PictureViewer extends Container implements MouseListener, ComponentListener
{
    java.util.List<Image> images;
    public Component leftSide, rightSide;
    int currentImage;
    boolean leftMoused, rightMoused;
    boolean mouseDown;
    Image leftTab, rightTab, noImage;

    public PictureViewer()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        addComponentListener(this);

        images = new ArrayList<Image>();

        leftSide = new Label();
        leftSide.setLocation(0, 0);
        leftSide.setSize(getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
        leftSide.addMouseListener(this);
        add(leftSide);

        rightSide = new Label();
        rightSide.setLocation(getWidth() / 2, 0);
        rightSide.setSize(getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
        rightSide.addMouseListener(this);
        rightSide.setVisible(false);
        add(rightSide);

        noImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("Images/No Picture.png"));
        leftTab = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("Images/Left Tab.png"));
        rightTab = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("Images/Right Tab.png"));
    }


    public void addImage(Image image)
    {
        images.add(image);
    }
    public void clear()
    {
        images.clear();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {       
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        Image imageToDraw;

        if (images.size() > 0)
        {
            imageToDraw = images.get(currentImage);
        }
        else
        {
            imageToDraw = noImage;
        }

        g2d.drawImage(imageToDraw, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0, imageToDraw.getWidth(this), imageToDraw.getHeight(this), this);
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20));

        if (leftMoused)
        {
            g2d.drawImage(leftTab, getX() + 8, getY() + (int)(getSize().getHeight() - leftTab.getHeight(this) / 2), this);
        }
    }

    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){}
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){}
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e)
    {
        componentResized(e);
    }
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
    {
        leftSide.setLocation(getLocation());
        leftSide.setSize(getWidth() / 2, getHeight());

        rightSide.setLocation((int)(getLocation().getX() + (getWidth() / 2)), (int)getLocation().getY());
        rightSide.setSize(leftSide.getSize());

        System.out.println(getSize());

        repaint();
    }   

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {   
    if (e.getComponent() == leftSide){
        leftMoused = true;
        System.out.println("Left");}
    else {
        rightMoused = true;
        System.out.println("Right");}

    repaint();
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {   
    if (e.getComponent() == leftSide)
        leftMoused = false;     
    else
        rightMoused = false;

    repaint();
    }   


}
```

Comment: or you're missing something fundamental to do with drawing on a JPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component will also have a `paintComponent` method which by default will paint the container's background.  You will need to override the method, `setOpaque` to false (depending on the component), or something else to keep painting from happening.

However, it sounds like what you really want is to add mouse listener to the panel and have it listen to a defined boundary instead the panel rather than adding a component to the panel.

Comment: Ooh, that sounds interesting. Do you have any links that could explain how to set a defined boundary?

Comment: The MouseEvent from the mouse listener will have an x and y position of the mouse.  You can use that to determine if it is inside a specific Rectangle or other Shape.

Comment: But will it then be possible to determine when it enters or exits regions within the JPanel?

Comment: You could use a MouseMotionListener and track its movement and determine yourself when it leaves or enters.

Comment: I'd been trying to avoid it for a slightly more elegant solution, but it seems there isn't one. I'll put that in, and hopefully there won't be any more problems.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't post any code right now

You wrote custom code that doesn't work and you expect us to guess what that code looks like? We don't have time to spend guessing what mistake you might have made. The point of the forums is to make it easy for us to answer the question which means you need to provide all the information we need to help solve the problem.

That is why you need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I was asking more about the specifics of mouseListener interfaces, but I'll put the code in now that my internet connection's back.

Comment: @Tharwen, that is not a SSCCE. The code is not executable. I still don't know how that component is used within your frame. Custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method (as has already been suggested) of a JPanel or JComponent.

Comment: It just needs to be added to a frame's `ContentPane` like any other component. Anyway, what do you mean by custom painting? Do you mean the code from my `paint` method should be put into an overloaded `paintComponent()` instead?

Comment: @Tharwen, if thats all that needs to be done then why didn't you do it. Why should the 5-10 of us who decided to test the code have to do it individually. We should be able to copy/paste. That is what a SSCCE is. Did you read the link? Yes, code should be moved from paint() to paintComonent() of a Swing component. I'll wait for updates before doing any testing of your code.

Comment: Actually, my comment about painting from above is for Swing, not AWT (in AWT you do override paint()). I don't know anything about AWT since people don't use it anymore, so I can't help out. I suggest you use Swing. Sorry for the confusion.